# Unique solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For what initial conditions the following differential equation 
$y'=\sqrt {(1-x^2-y^2)}$
has unique solution?\
Is Picard–Lindelöf theorem used for solving? How I'm supposed to get to answer, please some help

Comment: You should state the exact theorem you're referencing, and explain what you've tried.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: you don't want to take the square root of a negative number.  And for Lipschitz purposes, square root of $0$ may also be bad.

Comment: The condition must be $x^2+y^2<1$, but I don't know how to use that theorem to get to solution... Can you give me some more help?

Comment: That theorem come to my mind... May something other be used?

Comment: Your initial condition $y(x_0) = y_0$ should certainly satisfy $x_0^2 + y_0^2 \le 1$.  If it satisfies   $x_0^2 + y_0^2 < 1$, Picard-Lindelöf says there is a unique solution defined on some neighbourhood of $x_0$.  If it's $=1$, you **might** have a unique solution on one side of $x_0$, but further investigation would be needed.

Comment: So it holds that if $1-x^2-y^2$ is  Lipschitz continuous in $y$ then $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ is aslo Lipschitz in $y$?

Comment: $|1-t^2-x^2-1+t^2+y^2| \leq |y^2-x^2| \leq 2|x-y|$ so the Lipschitz constant is 2

Comment: No, $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ will have a problem when $x^2+y^2$ is near $1$.

Comment: But the above is true for $x^2+y^2<1$, right?

Comment: When $x^2 + y^2 < 1$, $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ is smooth, therefore locally Lipschitz.